# Firebase App Distribution emails not sent to testers

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

We have been using Firebase App Distribution for a while now, via Fastlane plugin:

```
fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution 0.2.3
fastlane version 2.160.0
```

Uploading the build in the Fastfile:

```
      firebase_app_distribution(
        app: "{app_id}",
        groups: "{testers}",
        release_notes: notes
      )
```

Normally when uploading a new app build to firebase, an email would be sent to all testers. This stopped working a few days ago. No emails are sent.

Manually inviting testers to a build via Firebase Console yields the same result. No emails.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Is it a known (new) Firebase platform issue?

Comment: Any news? I've only experience this problem when using gradle plugin, Firebase Console it's ok.

Comment: any update on this, I just had the same issue now